# Substract 2 columns SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table where i have 2 columns: salary and newsalary. I want to substract newsalary with salary and store it in a new column. How can i do that?

This isn't working:

```
SELECT employee_id, last_name, salary, round((salary * 0.155 + salary)) AS newsal, SUBSTR(newsal, salary) AS Increase FROM employees;
```

This also isn't working

```
SELECT employee_id, last_name, salary, round((salary * 0.155 + salary)) AS newsal, sum(newsal - salary) AS Increase FROM employees;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use alias as column name in select you must repeat the code and 
simply use minus

```
  SELECT employee_id
  , last_name
  , salary
  , round((salary * 0.155 + salary)) AS newsal
  , ( round(salary * 0.155 + salary) -salary) AS Increase 
  FROM employees;
```

or you can use a subselect as  table

```
select  employee_id
, last_name, salary
, (newsal - salary=  AS Increase
from (
SELECT employee_id
, last_name
, salary
, round((salary * 0.155 + salary)) AS newsal
FROM employees
) t
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It worked like a charm. Is there any way that i can use the newsal alias or do i need to calculate again?

Comment: answer  update  with a suggestion for avodi code repetition